# Calculating a Point's X position on an Ellipse, given pos Y

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

How can I calculate for the X coordinate given the Y value of the position? Which the Y position is 10 units, as seen in the image below.

We know the X diameter is 200 and the Y diameter is 150.

[image]

Comment: You are given all the information you need (center, major axis length, and semi major axis length) to write the equation of the ellipse. Once you have the equation just plug in the $y$ value you are given and solve for $x$.

Comment: @wgrenard would you be able to demonstrate what you mean by that? I'm not a math wizard :)

Comment: The answerers below have outlined it quite nicely :)

Comment: would you be willing to work through their equation and solve the answer. I not clear on how to use their equation to find the answer. I'm not sure where im going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ellipse equation here is
$$
\frac{x^2}{100^2} + \frac{y^2}{75^2} = 1
$$
so
$$
x = \pm\sqrt{100^2\left(1-\frac{y^2}{75^2}\right)}
= \pm 100 \sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{75^2}}
$$
Since you want a positive value (from your picture), pick the "+" in the $\pm$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what y2 means in the equation. wouldn't that just be the same as 75^2?

Comment: The symbol $y$ denotes the $y$-coordinate of the point you're trying to find, so in this case, $y = 10$.

Comment: got it working. thank you

Comment: At the end 100^2 is pulled out from under the sqrt to become 10? I would think it should be 100.

Comment: Thanks, @Buzz; I'll fix it. D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ellipse, you can use the standard equation for an ellipse:

$$\left( \frac{x}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 = 1,$$

where $a = \frac{200}{2}$ and $b = \frac{150}{2}$. Then you can find the $x$ value simply by substituting your $y = 10$ value and solving the above equation algebraically for $x$.

Note that when you solve for $x$, you will have to take a square root, which means you should have a $\pm$ in your answer (since there are two x-values for which $y = 10$).

You can read more information about ellipses here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equations