# Solve for $y$ in ellipse locus of points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Considering the following equation:

$$
\sqrt{\left(x_{F1}-x\right)^{2}+\left(y_{F1}-y\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\left(x_{F2}-x\right)^{2}+\left(y_{F2}-y\right)^{2}}=k
$$

With this equation being a locus of points that forms and ellipse, where:

$$
F1 = (x_{F1},y_{F1})
$$

$$
F2 = (x_{F2},y_{F2})
$$

As shown below:

[image: Ellipse diagram]

Source: *Wikipedia*

How would this equation be arranged for two solutions of y?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2195482/815585) will be helpful to you; write the ellipse equation differently!

Comment: @FShrike, I am restricted to this equation unfortunately :(

Comment: Always keeping one radical term in one side and then squaring both sides, you will see the terms with order higher than two will be cancelled completely.  **All conics are in second order.**  To make your life easy, try let the foci be $(\pm c,0)$, $k=2a$ and $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.